# Uncaught ReferenceError: Notification is not defined

Tags: javascript, push-notification

I thought my object detection would work:

```
if (Notification!=undefined) {}
```

However my JavaScript log is still showing the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Notification is not defined

How do I properly do object detection for the `Notification` object?

No frameworks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `typeof` like so:

```
if (typeof Notification !== 'undefined') {

}
```

If you use `typeof`, it does not try to actually **use** the variable (which breaks and throws an error)